# Getting statistics data from Google Store through API

Tags: android, api, google-play-console

We are developing a website which should be able to show statistics data related to our app from both Apple's app store and Google Play Store.

We have find out some way to get App Store's data and store those data in AWS Dynamodb. They provided API to retrieve those data by daily, monthly or yearly.

Is Google Play store provide that kind of API ?

How we store Google Play statistics data in our databases?

Answer (score 1):

> Google Play statistics are published to files on Google Cloud Storage

(https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6135870?p=financial_export&rd=1#export)

You can use the Google Cloud Storage API (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/apis) get the stat files.

Comment: Thank you ! Can you explain how do it using node js or ruby? Documentation is little bit unclearly to me.

Comment: In AWS use lambda to get insights from google cloud storage api and push it to dynamodb, using node js. Use this link to start https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html